# Locating WebElements using XPATH (NoSuchElementException)

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, arquillian-drone

I am having problems with locating elements using xpath while trying to write automated webUI tests with Arquillian Drone + Graphene. 
To figure things out I tried to locate the search-button on the [google homepage](https://www.google.com/). Even that I am not getting done. Neither with an absolute or a relative xpath.

However, I am able to locate elements using IDs or when the xpath string has an ID in it. But only when the ID is a real ID and is not generated. For example on google homepage: The google-logo has a real ID "hplogo". I can locate this element by using directly the ID or the ID within the xpath-expression.

Why is locating the google logo using the ID "hplogo" possible but it fails while using the absolute xpath `"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/span/center/div[1]/div/div"`?
I am really confused. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**:

`WebElement e = browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/span/center/div[1]/div/div"));`
is causing a NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression works on 
Firefox, but on webkit-based browser (e.g., chrome) the rendered DOM is a bit different.  Maybe it depends on localization (google.co.uk for me). If I force on google.com the image logo for me is: 
`/html/body/div/div[5]/span/center/div[1]/img` on firefox 37 and `/html/body/div/div[6]/span/center/div[1]/img` on Chome 42.

EDIT:
After discussing in chat, we figure out that HTMLUNIT is indeed creating a DOM that is different from the one real browsers render. Suggested to migrate to FirefoxDriver

Comment: How is the rendered DOM different? Your xpath expression isn't working for me.

Comment: Can you identify what browser is using your code? I can post  screenshots that show that your expression works in  firefox 37 but not in chrome 42. Maybe it depends on localization (google.co.uk for me). 
If I force on google.com the image logo for me is:     `/html/body/div/div[5]/span/center/div[1]/img`  on firefox and  `/html/body/div/div[6]/span/center/div[1]/img` on Chome.

Comment: It is using htmlUnit. My problem doesn't have explicitly something to do with the google homepage or the localization. I get the same error (NoSuchElementException) when using xpath on other websites.

Comment: ok, htmlunit is tricky. Are you saying that any expression on any site does not work? For instance if you run `/html` will it work?

Comment: also, try to test a website less difficult for htmlunit (it struggles with javascript). Something more static, like wikipedia, just to give a try

Comment: When I try /html on google homepage, I get a WebDriverException: Cannot determine size of element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81865/discussion-between-legrass-and-marco).